# AWS Serverless Application Model: Create S3 Event to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I would like to use the Serverless Application Model(SAM) and CloudFormation to create a simple lambda function which gets triggered when an object is created in a S3 bucket(e.g. `thescore-cloudfront-trial`). How do I enable the trigger from the S3 bucket to the Lambda Function? Below is my python3 boto3 code.

```
    region = 'us-east-1'
    import boto3

    test_lambda_template = {
        'AWSTemplateFormatVersion': '2010-09-09',
        'Transform': 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31',
        'Resources': {
            'CopyS3RajivCloudF': {
                'Type': 'AWS::Serverless::Function',

                'Properties': {
                    "CodeUri": 's3://my-tmp/CopyS3Lambda',
                    "Handler": 'lambda.handler',
                    "Runtime": 'python3.6',
                    "Timeout": 300,
                    "Role": 'my_existing_role_arn'
                },
                'Events': {
                    'Type': 'S3',
                    'Properties': {
                        "Bucket": "thescore-cloudfront-trial",
                        "Events": 's3:ObjectCreated:*'

                    }

                }
            },
            'SrcBucket': {
                "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
                "Properties": {
                    "BucketName": 'thescore-cloudfront-trial',
                }
            }

        }

    }

    conf = config.get_aws_config('development')
    client = aws.client(conf, 'cloudformation', region_name=region)
    response = client.create_change_set(
         StackName='RajivTestStack',
         TemplateBody=json.dumps(test_lambda_template),
         Capabilities=['CAPABILITY_IAM'],
         ChangeSetName='a',
         Description='Rajiv ChangeSet Description',
         ChangeSetType='CREATE'
     )

    response = client.execute_change_set(
        ChangeSetName='a',
        StackName='RajivTestStack',
    )
```

Comment: Have you considered reading [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)?

Comment: 1. Add a trigger in your S3 bucket using AWS console.  2. Use boto3 to add your events  :  http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_notification_configuration

Comment: @mootmoot: I already have python scripts doing what you listed :). I want to move to SAM.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with caveats

Caveat 1: The trigger notification will show up in S3 console but not in the Lambda console. My existing python deploy scripts using boto3 s3 and lambda clients(which I want to replace) show the notification in both consoles.

Caveat 2: For monitoring, I see my lambda trigger only when I switch to see the lambda alias view. But I haven't specified an alias for my lambda. So I don't know why I don't see it in the non alias view(just seeing the LATEST version)

I had to modify the `Events` key like this:

```
'Events': {
   'RajivCopyEvent': {
      'Type': 'S3',
      'Properties': {
         "Bucket": {"Ref": "SrcBucket"},
         "Events": "s3:ObjectCreated:*"

      }
    }

}
```